# Changing order of colours in R plot (avoiding faint yellow)

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting data in R in a manhattan plot and I have different colours for the different sub categories of data. Unfortunately one of the sub catagories that I want to be clear in the plot is in really faint yellow. Is there a way to change the order of the colors just to avoid that sub category being yellow, or to exclude yellow? Either solution would work.

My current command is like this:

```
 plot(-log10(1-emp_dis_Fst(xdata[,"MEAN_FST_TAME_AGGRESSIVE"])), col=xdata$CHROM, pch=16)
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Rubal

Comment: `?palette` should help

Comment: thanks this looks like it should solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#Look at the color palette
palette()
#[1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray" 

#change the palette
col.pal <- palette()
col.pal[7] <- "purple"
palette(col.pal)

#plot
plot(rnorm(10),col=1:10)

#reset the palette
palette("default")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just tell R to treat your one category special:

```
plot(-log10(1-emp_dis_Fst(xdata[,"MEAN_FST_TAME_AGGRESSIVE"]))
     ,col=ifelse(xdata$CHROM==badCategory,"red",xdata$CHROM
     , pch=16)
```

Here's a simplified example

```
x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)
colr = seq(from=1, to=5)

plot(x,y, col=colr)
plot(x,y, col=ifelse(colr==3, "purple", colr))
```